# How to make git fetch/pull --all the default?

Tags: git

Is it possible to make `git fetch`, `git pull`, etc. use the `--all` flag by default?
I have branches tracking different upstream repositories and I'd like to be able to fetch them all without extra typing.

I tried aliasing the commands in my global `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    fetch = fetch --all
    pull = pull --all
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to do this for fetch.  Use `git remote update` instead.  See [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

Don't use `git pull`; it's not adequate here.  Use `git remote update` first, then use `git merge` or `git rebase` with appropriate additional arguments if needed.

Comment: Nice, somehow I never noticed the `update` subcommand for `git remote`.

Comment: That's good for interactive command line operations, but what about existing (shared) scripts and tools which use fetch/merge?

Comment: @AlexO: Non-interactive code should already be running separate fetch-and-merge; teach it to run the appropriate fetch (with `--all`) or `git remote update` as needed. Scripts in general should be written with care since they have to work (or stop appropriately) even if a user might notice: *Hey, that didn't do the right thing, I'd better stop and figure out what happened...*

Comment: Is there a difference between `git fetch --all` and `git remote update`?  The information I could find implies they are identical.  Similarly, is there a difference between `git pull --all` and `git remote update` followed by `git merge`?

Comment: @AlexO: the only real difference is *supposed* to be exit code, plus the fact that `git remote update` understands the concepts of groups, so that you can get fancy. However, there were once some bugs where `--prune` worked differently for the two commands. The group stuff for `git remote update` is the really useful thing here since you'll find that you want some remotes updated with different frequency than others.

Comment: The main drawback to using `git pull --all` is that if some of the fetches fail, it's not clear whether pull as a whole should fail, or not. So once again we're looking at specific exit codes. Unfortunately the exit codes for `git remote update` aren't documented, so we can't really count on them (a bug IMO).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the other part, (but accept @torek's answer, that's the goods), you can't alias the built-in commands. They work as they're documented to work, with their documented defaults, because a little light scripting is basically the air we breathe and if you could alter how they behave then talking about them would become a tar pit, there'd be no shared context for communication. If you've got incorporating new upstream work into your history choreographed, give the dance its own name, something more entertaining than `git xpull`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not going to give you a detailed answer here, but if you are on Linux you can try to make an alias for that certain command with whatever keyword you like to use.

I would not suggest you change that default command instead create another for you. Sort of creating a command for executing another command. You can find those settings in the .bashrc file.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.